# librsvg library crashing in release mode

Tags: visual-studio, crash, librsvg

recently I've been trying to write an application that draws SVG pictures. I'm using librsvg library in order to do so. I found a static library file "librsvg-2.dll.a" somewhere and it seemed to do the trick.

The problem is that it crashes in release mode on rsvg_init() function call. I have no idea how to cope with that. Perhaps anyone is able to share their experience.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this issue is solved. I managed to build the .lib file in Visual Studio 2005 and it did the trick.